# Why is the class name skipped when we import a package using the static keyword in java?

Tags: java

Normally when we create a static method we refer to it by using the classname.method() statement, thus the static keyword allows us to call the method without creating any class object but we do have to write the name of the class.

Why in case of static import do we skip the class name?

example:-

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        out.print("Where is the class name?");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Isn't that a compiler error?](http://ideone.com/BGNQJU)

Comment: Code from your example will not compile. You can't use `out.println` without specifying from which class `out` comes from. You need `import static java.lang.System.out;` so you need always to specify class name.

Comment: @Pshemo you know people like you love pouncing on other people's mistakes Because it makes them feel better beatin up on someone else. And they're greatful it ain't them thats being humiliated.

Comment: I am not doing this to humiliate you, I am trying to be nice guy here. I just pointed that your example wouldn't compile so you could change it to improve your question. I even showed you how you can fix it and explained why problem occurred. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @Pshemo I'm a newbie and i find downvoting my question offensive!

Comment: @Arya And why are you telling it me? Anyway if you take a look at tooltip at downvote arrow (place your mouse over it and wait a little bit) you will see when people should use it: "*question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*". Try to think if any of this reasons could be applied here (notice that vote appeared before your edit so it was about your previous version of your post, also person who cast it could not be here any more to remove it).

Comment: @Pshemo couldn't you just upvote it? I just don't wanna get blocked!!

Comment: Sorry but no. I am doing you a favour by not voting at all. Anyway one downvote will not get you question-banned, you just need to start paying attention at your questions. Check if it is clear, if your code examples are actually reproducing your problem, maybe include current output and desired one in case of handling data. There are many hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-list), or [FAQ created by users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 2):

```
import static java.lang.*;
```

This is a bad syntax . It will result in compilation error. Package import  does not  use static key word.

Syntax  for importing  static fields is:

`import  static <package>.<classname>.* ;`  or

`import  static <package>.<classname>.<fieldname>;` or

`import  static <package>.<classname>.<methodname>;`

You could do

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        out.print("Where is the class name?");
    }
}
```

You can take a looks at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can skip the class name after doing a static import is because static imports were created to let you skip the class name. It's the only reason they were added to the language.

**Before:**

```
public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value = Math.sin(0.523598776); // 30 degrees in radians
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**After:**

```
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value = sin(0.523598776); // 30 degrees in radians
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

The `static` keyword here is not related to the other usage of the `static` keyword, to declare a `static` method or a `static` field. They simply wanted to find some syntax to allow this, without introducing a new keyword to the language, so they reused an existing keyword for a new purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. `import static java.lang.*;` will be a compile time error. To import static member you will have to mention `import static java.lang.<Classname>.<field_member>`